# How to add multiple auto-renewable subscriptions in iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, auto-renewing

Our iOS app currently provides a monthly auto-renewable subscription. However, its price is fixed for all countries.

We'd like to implement a different price-per-country strategy (not just currency conversion), where for example people in France will pay an equivalent to 5$ per month while people in Germany will pay an equivalent to 6$ per month.

To implement this, we want to create more than one auto-renewable subscription in itunes connect, then in the app we'll fetch the `SKProduct` of the desired subscription based on a country-to-subscription map we have in our server.

Having said the above, we're currently not able to add any new auto-renewable subscriptions in iTunes connect. We navigate to the in-app purchases tab, click "Create New", select "Auto-Renewable Subscriptions" then the following message appears:

> To add an auto-renewable subscription duration to an existing family, select a family from the table below. Note that each duration can only be used once per family. To begin a new family of subscriptions, click Create New Family.

I don't want to add a new duration to our current subscription family, I need a new subscription family which will have a different price for the same period (1  month). However, I can't find the "Create New Family" button anywhere. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Almost one year later, the "Create new family" button still does not exist, but the "Create new" button seems to do it.